# PHP echo with HTML markup not rendering HTML, displaying as plaintext

Tags: php, html

I'm attempting to use Walmart API to display some information about a product.

The API returns a json object which I converted to a regular array and am simply using echo to show this data.

The problem is, when I get to the `longDescription` variable from the API, it contains HTML - which is fine, but it is not being rendered, instead it is displaying it all as plain text. Here is my code:

```
echo "<p id='longDescription'>";
    echo $obj['longDescription'];
echo "</p>";
```

This is what is contained in the `$obj['longDescription']` variable:

```
<br><b>HP 15-ay039wm 15.6" Laptop:</b><br><br><b>Key Features and Benefits:</b>
<ul>
    <li>15.6" Display<br>HD (1366 x 768) SVA Brightview WLED-backlit Display<br><br></li>
    <li>Intel Core i3-6100U Dual-Core Processor<br>2.3GHz<br><br></li>
    <li>8GB system memory<br>Gives you the power to handle most power-hungry applications and tons of multimedia work<br><br></li>
    <li>1TB Hard Drive<br>Store 666,000 photos, 285,000 songs or 526 hours of HD video and more<br><br></li>
    <li>6 hours of battery life<br>Long-lasting battery life gives you plenty of access to your photos, videos, music and documents<br><br></li>
    <li>Intel HD Graphics 520<br>With up to 4169MB of graphics memory<br><br></li>
    <li>Weight: 4.73 lbs<br>Thin design you can easily take on the road<br><br></li>
    <li>SuperMulti DVD burner<br>Watch movies and read and write CDs and DVDs in multiple formats<br><br></li>
    <li>10/100 Base-T Ethernet, 802.11ac Wireless LAN<br>Connect to a broadband modem with wired Ethernet or wirelessly connect to a WiFi signal or hotspot with the 802.11ac connection built into your PC</li>
</ul>
<br><b>Additional Features:</b>
<ul>
    <li>HP TrueVision HD Webcam</li>
    <li>Multi-Format Digital memory card reader</li>
    <li>Bluetooth</li>
    <li>1 x USB 3.0 port, 2 x USB 2.0 ports, 1 x HDMI out port, 1 x audio out/in jack, 1 x RJ-45 Ethernet port</li>
    <li>3-cell lithium-ion battery</li>
    <li>Dimensions: 0.95" x 15.12" x 10.02"</li>
    <li>Color: Silver</li>
</ul>
<br><b>Software:</b>
<ul>
    <li>Genuine Microsoft Windows 10</li>
    <li>McAfee LiveSafe (30-day trial)</li>
    <li>Backup and Restore options built into Windows allow you to create safety copies of your most important personal files, so you're always prepared for the worst</li>
</ul>
<br><b>Support and Warranty:</b>
<ul>
    <li>1-year limited hardware warranty; 24/7 technical assistance available online or toll-free by phone</li>
    <li>Restore discs are not included (unless specified by supplier). We recommend you use the installed software to create your own restore and backup DVD the first week you use the computer.</li>
</ul>
<br><b>What's In The Box:</b>
<ul>
    <li>Power cord and AC adapter</li>
    <li>3-cell battery</li>
    <li>Quick Start Guide</li>
</ul>
<br><b><i>To see the manufacturer's specifications for this product, click <a href="http://i.walmart.com/i/rb/0088989980651.pdf" target="_blank">here</a>.<br><br>To see a list of our PC Accessories, click <a href="http://www.walmart.com/cp/accessories-peripherals/132959" target="_blank">here</a>.<br><br>Trade in your used computer and electronics for more cash to spend at Walmart. Good for your wallet and the environment - click <a href="http://gazelle.com/register_click?campaign=electronics_trade_in&media_type=text&network=walmart&destination_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwalmart.gazelle.com&placement=product_computers&creative=learn_more" target="_blank">here</a>.</i></b><br><br><b>ENERGY STAR<sup>®</sup></b><br>Products that are ENERGY STAR-qualified prevent greenhouse gas emissions by meeting strict energy efficiency guidelines set by the U.S. Environmental Protection Agency and the U.S. Department of Energy. The ENERGY STAR name and marks are registered marks owned by the U.S. government, as part of their energy efficiency and environmental activities.
```

I'm not really sure where to begin with this or what to do, I have never had this problem before.

*How can I output this variable as rendered HTML?*

Comment: Yes, it is. Only the variable isn't being rendered, when I inspect element the entire variable is wrapped in quotes, but everything else is fine

Comment: Try inserting this php var longDescription in a div, not in a <p>.

Comment: @Roy Same problem when it's in a div

Comment: try echo htmlentities($obj['longDescription']); OR html_entity_decode

Comment: @Roy html_entity_decode seems to have worked :)

Comment: Use "view source" to look at the information.  You may be seeing the browser's rendering of HTML entities.

Comment: Nice! can i put it in answer and mark it like solved?

Comment: @roy yes please

Comment: Thx! and good coding!

Comment: @Roy I'm hoping to hit 1k Rep on here soon ^.^ Thanks again!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using **html_entity_decode()**
[Convert all HTML entities to their applicable characters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

> More precisely, this function decodes all the entities (including all
>   numeric entities) that 
> **a)** are necessarily valid for the chosen
>   document type — i.e., for XML, this function does not decode named
>   entities that might be defined in some DTD — and 
> **b)** whose character or
>   characters are in the coded character set associated with the chosen
>   encoding and are permitted in the chosen document type. All other
>   entities are left as is.

Answer (score 4):

The output is probably being rendered with

`&lt;`

which outputs "<". This is most likely your problem.

You can use the php function

`htmlspecialchars_decode()`

Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: It wasn't being rendered with encoded entities, it was being displayed with the tags, like a string. It wasn't rendering at all except plaintext. However, using `html_entity_decode` fixed it, so your solution probably would too.

Comment: Yes, as you said it does render like a string, but the code that is being sent to your pc is "`&lt;`" instead of "<". This causes it to be displayed on the screen has a lower then instead of use as a tag in html. This is the explanation why html_entity_decode and htmlspecialchars_decode is working as it converts the lower than bracket to a usable tag for HTML.

Comment: But on inspect element, it displays with the tags, not as encoded entities - maybe thats an inspect element thing

Comment: No, it just shows the tag as text, as if it was the text to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to render html you muct have to decode it.

Here i mention few fuctions to decode it.

1. `wp_specialchars_decode()` if you are using WordPres.
2. `htmlspecialchars_decode()` Normal PHP funcion.
3. `html_entity_decode()` also, Normal PHP function.

Solution:

```
<?php 
     // This work for me:
     echo wp_specialchars_decode($your_html_code, ENT_QUOTES);

     // try this if above code doesn't work
     // echo htmlspecialchars_decode($your_html_code);
     // try this if above code doesn't work
     // echo html_entity_decode($your_html_code, ENT_HTML5);
?>
```

---

The rest of the two functions inspired by **@Roy Bogado** and **@Firelumet**'s answer.

Comment: I don't think that this whole extra answer is necessary just to include the `echo` at the beginning. It should have just been a comment.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I update my answer now this may help you and others.